# Issue with Alexa SessionId

Tags: session-state, alexa-skills-kit

I created a skill which plays small audio using Audio tag in SSML tag and after that audio I am asking few questions to the user, whether he or she wants to hear something else, The answer should be in YES or No and I uses inbuilt YesIntent and NoIntent to process the user answer and storing question state in session attributes. I created a c# function to process the request and put it on azure function. I enabled this skill for beta testing and shared with few testers. Alexa plays audio and ask questions successfully and proceed as per my workflow if there is an only single request or single tester test it. If two or more tester tests the same skill at the same time, Alexa session id replaced with the latest request session id. For example Tester T1 request Alexa skill, then Alexa launches my skill and gave ABC123Tester1 as SessionID and start playing audio that I set, after 2 or 3 seconds Tester T2 start same skill, then Alexa launches my skill and gave 123ABCTester2 as SessionID, after request from Tester2, the sessionID of Tester1 is replaced with Tester2 SessionID means SessionID for Tester1 is Set as 123ABCTester2 and after this, flow of questions is messed up, like if 1 question asked to Tester1, then it directly ask 2nd question to Tester2 and so on. If Tester2 provide an answer to Alexa before Tester2, then Alexa asks the 3rd question to Tester2 and ask the 4th question to Tester1. This happens because SessionID replace. Is there a way to fix this issue.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Note that the starting audio length is about 15 seconds.

Thanks

Javed

Answer (score 0):

So there is no issue with Alexa Session. **Alexa maintains session per user**, and *I was trying to access skill with same user id on two different system*, which raises an issue. I tried with two different user id and access the same skill at the same time and issue gone. There is no session issue, and skill executed as per my workflow.